# Display modified confirm on the button submit from button action

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hi I am using an ajax confirm button  like so and when the button is clicked instead of seeing  ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to click this?" I want it to display my text passed from the code behind.

```
    <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="cbe" runat="server"
   TargetControlID="Cancel"
           ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to click this?"
         />
```

then in the code behind i have a method like

```
public void display()
{
   string error="my error";
   cbe.ConfirmText = error;

}
```

then my button action

```
protected void Cancel_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {   display();
            anothermethod();
            Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
        }
```

The question that instead of seeing "my error" on confirm when I click on cancel button. I see "Are you sure you want to click this?" which is the default one. **Is there any way update the `ConfirmButtonExtender`  when button is clicked or on buttonpostback.  Or any other solutions thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you'd want to change the client-side confirm dialogue text on the server-side event that the button itself fires?

Regardlss, if you want to set the error message programatically, you can do it *before* you hit the Cancel button:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string error = "my error";
        cbe.ConfirmText = error;
    }
}
```